# How can I see which contacts have been assigned which roles and permissions?

Tags: permissions, roles

How can i find out which contacts have been assigned which roles? I am looking to ensure that only a few key staff can access and edit our database...
I can see we have two roles set up but I don't know how to find out who has been assigned which role...

Comment: What CMS are you on? In Drupal you can see this via the Drupal menu --> People
I dont know how to do this in Wordpress or Joomla.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SE! The place to start is in the documentation about roles and permissions at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/

It does depend on the CMS as Jaap says, but they are all covered here. You will see who is assigned to which role in the CMS (Its under Users in WordPress) but then you need to allocate permisssions to these rolls to control which CiviCRM features each role has. There are some more complex option too, with roles and permissions specific to CiviCRM, but you probably don't need these.